# Travis fails to launch simulator on xcode8

Tags: ios, travis-ci, xcode8

I am having issue with Travis building and testing a new ios app I am being developing.

```
language: objective-c
os: osx
osx_image: xcode8
before_install:
   - pod repo update > /dev/null
   - pod update
   - gem install xcpretty
script:
    - xcodebuild clean test -workspace project.xcworkspace -scheme project -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
```

This is my .travis.yml and everytime I run it Travis get me this error:

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:latest, name:iPhone 6 }
    Ineligible destinations for the "project" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Device }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Simulator Device }
The command "xcodebuild clean test -workspace project.xcworkspace -scheme project -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO" exited with 70.
```

I also tried putting the id of the simulator with the same result.
Please note that the same xcodebuild command is building without any issue in my workarea.

Comment: Try `-sdk iphonesimulator -destination "OS=10.0,name=iPhone 7"`

Comment: No still the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your `iOS Deployment Target` value in `Build Settings` is set to a value that your osx image on Travis supports.

If your app is brand new, the iOS Deployment Target may be set to 10.1. The newest image Travis is providing comes with Xcode 8.0, which does not have iOS 10.1 simulators in them yet.

Comment: Wonderful thanks. That solved the issue. I have the issue related to "Error 65". But that is another story! ;)

Comment: Man, thank you so much. I really have spent many hours trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Travis-CI is supporting xcode8.1 and iOS 10.1